# Android Camera get parameter issue on commonsguy/cwac-camera

Tags: android, camera, commonsware-cwac

I used commonsguy/cwac-camera for a custom camera view, image capturing is working fine, but when trying to start recording video, the app crashed.

My Stack trace is this,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: getParameters failed (empty parameters)
at android.hardware.Camera.native_getParameters(Native Method)
at android.hardware.Camera.getParameters(Camera.java:2112)
at com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraView$OnOrientationChange.onOrientationChanged(CameraView.java:658)
at android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl.onSensorChanged(OrientationEventListener.java:143)
at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$ListenerDelegate$1.handleMessage(SystemSensorManager.java:261)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Activity is strictly in portrait mode, recording is working fine in MOTO G, but not in Samsung Tab and Micromax, getting same error.

Also I used latest version of "commonsguy/cwac-camera"

One Micromax Device Model is A114 (4.2.2) where i getting the error

Comment: Please do not both open an issue *and* ask a question here on Stack Overflow. Since you opened an issue, I replied to you there: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/192

Comment: Ok, Thank you , should i delete this from stack overflow

Comment: Deleting it would be a good idea, if you could. Thanks!